# layout and other thing

Tags: rstudio, markdown, r-markdown

I want to write a report in Markdown under Rstudio, I have already written several documents in Latex, from what I understood you can write latex commands under Markdown. I am on the first page where there is the title, name, ect.

I would like to know how:

- put an image above the title.
- make two columns one for the author and the other for the referents.
- put a subtitle.

  title: "titre"
  author: "nom"
  date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
  output:
    pdf_document:
      latex_engine: pdflatex
    #html_document:
      #latex_engine: pdflatex
  fontsize: 14pt
  documentclass: report

Comment: this hasn't much to do with markdown but is essentially a LaTeX question...

Comment: i can't add a image in the first page with the command : \includegraphics[width=6cm]{../logo.png}